# chart.js typeError t is undefined and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am having trouble running chart.js in my website, the stand alone html version works fine for me in localhost as well on webserver, however when I put the same in my site, it flags following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined
    at Object._parseFont (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at i.fit (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at i.update (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at chart.js@2.8.0:7
    at Object.each (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at Object.update (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at ni.updateLayout (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at ni.update (chart.js@2.8.0:7)
    at i.<anonymous> (chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0:7)
_parseFont @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
fit @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
update @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
(anonymous) @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
each @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
update @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
updateLayout @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
update @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
(anonymous) @ chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0:7
n.onreadystatechange @ chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0:7
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
request @ chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0:7
beforeUpdate @ chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0:7
notify @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
update @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
construct @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
ni @ chart.js@2.8.0:7
window.onload @ chart1.js:90
load (async)
(anonymous) @ chart1.js:88
```

I have put my js code for chart in a separate file chart1.js, content of which as follows.

```
var chartColors = {
                        red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                        orange: 'rgb(255,127,80)',
                        blue2: 'rgb(0,204,204)'
                };

                var color = Chart.helpers.color;
                var config = {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                                datasets: [{
                                        type: 'line',
                                        yAxisID: 'heapUsed',
                                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                        borderColor: chartColors.red,
                                        pointBackgroundColor: chartColors.red,
                                        tension: 0,
                                        fill: false
                                },
                                {
                                        type: 'line',
                                        yAxisID: 'heapUsed',
                                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                        borderColor: chartColors.orange,
                                        pointBackgroundColor: chartColors.orange,
                                        tension: 0,
                                        fill: false
                                },
                                {
                                        yAxisID: 'processCpuLoad',
                                        backgroundColor: color(chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                                        borderColor: 'transparent'
                                },
                                {
                                        yAxisID: 'processCpuLoad',
                                        backgroundColor: color(chartColors.blue2).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                                        borderColor: 'transparent'
                                }]
                        },
                        plugins: [ChartDataSource],
                        options: {
                                title: {
                                        display: true,
                                        text: 'CSV data source (dataset) sample'
                                },
                                scales: {
                                        xAxes: [{
                                                scaleLabel: {
                                                        display: true,
                                                        labelString: 'Time'
                                                }
                                        }],
                                        yAxes: [{
                                                id: 'heapUsed',
                                                gridLines: {
                                                        drawOnChartArea: false
                                                },
                                                scaleLabel: {
                                                        display: true,
                                                        labelString: 'heapUsed(MB)'
                                                }
                                        }, {
                                                id: 'processCpuLoad',
                                                position: 'right',
                                                gridLines: {
                                                        drawOnChartArea: false
                                                },
                                                scaleLabel: {
                                                        display: true,
                                                        labelString: 'processCpuLoad (%)'
                                                }
                                        }]
                                },
                                plugins: {
                                        datasource: {
                                                type: 'csv',
                                                url: 'sample-dataset.csv',
                                                delimiter: ',',
                                                rowMapping: 'dataset',
                                                datasetLabels: true,
                                                indexLabels: true
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                };

                window.onload = function() {
                        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                        window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
                };
```

and my html inside a div.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="chart">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0"></script>
    <script src="chart1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried with different versions of chart.js, all give same error, there are many questions in stack related to same error, I tried all of them but none worked, hence posting for guidance.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle replicating your issue ?

Comment: Thank Prince for reply, I will create a fiddle and share shortly.